# How to convert NSString to NSMutableString in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to convert an NSString to NSMutableString in Objective-C?

Answer (score 28):

```
NSString *string = @"A string.";
NSMutableString *mutableString = [string mutableCopy];
```